# Which is more efficient: One long Single Table or Distributed Table? and Why?

Tags: mysql, database-design

This question is all about performance and I would appreciate if the answers are specific to the case I provide.

Which is more appropriate performance-wise?

- creating a table with too many fields
- creating more than one table and distributing similar fields to them

**CASE: An Extensive Web CMS Module**

Pattern 1: Long but one table

```
cms
-----------------------------------------------
Id
Title
Description
Images
Order
Status
Publish
meta_keywords
meta_description
meta_author
```

Cleary, most the Open Source CMS like joomla use the above pattern. But i think, that pattern is **killing the spirit of RDBMS**. We can easily separate the content, configuration and meta of a particular article to different tables. Like the following

Pattern 2: Many but related table

```
Cms_content         cms_meta        cms_configuration
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id                  id              id          
Title               content_id      content_id
Description         keywords        status
Content             description     order
Images              author          publish
```

**Note: Relations in this case is one-to-one**

Which is the proper pattern to follow? Why choose a long but one table, or why not to choose distributed tables, over the single table?

Comment: "Proper" always depends on aims and on cases of usage. There is no silver bullet

Comment: @zerkms, agreed that's why I provided a case too :)

Comment: Oh, you meant that is a "case". Ok. Any reason to split the **single** entity into the parts? The fields belong to the same entity, this schema does its work. So don't touch the thing that works ;-)

Comment: @zerkms, I dont know, that's why i asked. But in my opinion, one for manageability and two for efficiency. When, I am displaying the content of a article, I dont need to import the configurataion or meta portion. Or lets say, when i am only updating the status, I dont need to touch other two table, thus giving smaller workload to the server. P.S. Just an opinion... I am not expert at this...

Comment: I think the rules for [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) are defined pretty well and provide an established guideline for database design. It's also common practice to de-normalize via views etc. where needed for ease of use and performance.

Comment: @Starx: "I dont need to import the configurataion or meta portion" --- so don't specify those fields in `SELECT`. Do you experience any performance issues? Have you determined that the performance issues caused by this specific table? No? So - don't panic yet ;-)

Comment: @zerkms, But I thought `SELECT * ...` was faster than` SELECT field1, field2 ... `

Comment: I read an article, somewhere, wait I will try to find it.

Comment: @Starx: as Filburt pointed out before: design the data as normalized as you can. And denormalize/optimize schema only when you found that current schema cannot satisfy performance requirements. The performance is a vague subject and there is no universal solutions that work in each particular case, it is always a challenge

Comment: @Starx: `SELECT *` is never faster in case that you don't need all the fields

Comment: @zerkms, so a table with 42 field is normalized, if they relate to single entity.

Comment: @Starx: not actually. It is required, but not the sufficient criteria - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only possible plausible causes for having denormalized data (one table with many columns) I can think of, are:

- laziness in writing SQL `JOIN`s
- possible performance improvements on read statements

I like to go for the normalised version all the time, because:

- I can be sure of data integrity
- I can extract easily information from the DB (for example, how many posts have some meta, how many distinct metas there are, etc)

Comment: Why did you say that `denormalized data (one table with many columns)`? All the fields belong to the **same entity**. So the single table **is normalized** too

Comment: Exactly, why even care about reading the metas, when you are just listing the article one by one.

Comment: @Starx: don't read metas by specifying exact fields you need in `SELECT`

Comment: @zerkms - `meta_keywords` sounds to me like there are many entities serialized in a single field. Also, there are cases where [1 to 1 relationships](http://www.databaseprimer.com/relationship_1to1.html) are also perfectly acceptable

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: in the link you gave you have 2 different entities, while in the question it is the only one: module. I suppose there is a string of keywords. And, yes, I agree it is a candidate to move out. But the only candidate.

Comment: @zerkms - what about the `Images` column? regarding entities, I think `meta` could be also considered a separate entity

Comment: @zerkms, I also read that article and it points out `if the height, weight and dateofbirth columns are rarely used, it may make sense to separate them out into a separate database table`. And, I think both tables, represent a single entity `customer`. So hows the case different than I provided.

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: oh, Images too :-S If it is a serialized string - then you're absolutely right, sorry and +1

Comment: @Starx: don't optimize before it is really necessary. Premature optimization bla-bla-bla, you know it ;-)

Comment: Since, the community voted for this. I am going to accept this as my solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key of **performance** on 'modern' - I don't know much about the meaning of 'modern', but - RDBMS based application not only depends on **database schema**.

- Database settings : memory usage strategy, key buffer size, query cache size, etc.
- Distribution on data/processing : partitioning, grid processing.
- Cache strategy : using embedded cache engine or other( like memcached ).
- Hardware performance

So, estimating performance is not a simple problem. Even a table with 100 fields can be fitted in memory, but also even two-fields-table may cannot be. A query for 5M rows can be done under one minute, but sometime same query does not end for 10 mins on 10M rows (only twice!) - it depends on environment that I mentioned above.

Thus, I think we cannot choose the best practice for entire cases. For your example, the key is dangled on DBA's taste. (not joke)

Comment: I didn't understand the part, `the key is dangled on DBA's taste`. Since its not a joke, please explain

Comment: These tables will not be well optimized by just 'dividing', generally. Because there'll be only 1:1 relationships between tables.

About dividing, I agree with @TudorConstantin, but I think breaking one may field table into 3 tables or 5 tables or 10 tables is not a big issue for performance. And also, this is not a huge database for aggregation, map/reduce, analytics or grid-like application, right? 

So, I wrote `It's DBA's taste`.